# Why a C2259 when the problem is utterly different in nature?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When trying to compile the snippet below, I got the error stated:

```
error C2259: 'cTest': cannot instantiate abstract class
note: due to the following members:
note: void iTest::log(iTest::eLevel): is abstract
note: see declaration of 'iTest::log'
```

The abstract member function has been defined with the same signature.

Removing the second enum solves the problem though, it wasn't intended anyway.

But still I don't know why a C2259 is given and I can only find that the member should be defined to fix.

```
class iTest
{
public:
    enum eLevel
    {
        Info,
    };
    virtual void foo( eLevel l ) = 0;
};

class cTest : public iTest
{
public:
    enum eLevel
    {
        Info,
    };
    virtual void foo( eLevel l )
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    iTest* t = new cTest();
}
```

Comment: please post failing code, with the error message. Its not clear from your question

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75ea95d5b546e460).  Please [edit] this with a [mcve]

Comment: Missing semicolons after the enums. This is not valid code.

Comment: This is fantasy code. We need the *real* offending text. Fixing the typos in this  results in [CNR](https://ideone.com/UOajSP), but we have no earthly idea whether what we fixed is because it was a typo from your phone, or because it is in your real code.

Comment: @nathanoliver and other, my apologies

Comment: The compiler mentions `C2259` because [that's the MSVC error code for trying to instantiate an abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2259?view=vs-2017). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @WhozCraig hope it is better. But is isn't nor wasn't fantasy code. Ever tried a cell phone on SO. It is horrible, the phone is just too small.

Comment: @melpomene the error is the second declaration of eLevel. Not the member function log.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with declaring another type, even if it has the same name as a type in another class. Also, your member function is called `foo`, not `log`. Also, it's abstract because `iTest::eLevel` is a different type from `cTest::eLevel`, so `void cTest::foo( cTest::eLevel ) {}` cannot be an implementation of `virtual void iTest::foo( iTest::eLevel )` because they have different signatures.

Comment: right, foo(). Alright, compiler expects a iTest::eLevel but chooses to fil in cTest::eLevel. Thanks.

Comment: btw, what's the code tag in comment. Can't look it op in the cellphone.

Comment: Note: You would have gotten a better error message with `void foo( eLevel l ) override`. Another note: Once a virtual function is overridden, it is automatically virtual. No need for the `virtual` keyword in derived classes.

Comment: Several lessons learned here, today.

Comment: Code tag in comment '`'s to open and close. See the help link under the add comment button for more fun stuff you can do in comments.

Comment: There isn't a help link on the mobile website. I checked before asking. `thought it was ', so close`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is because the second definition of `iTest::foo` and `cTest::foo` do not have the same signature and thus `ctest` does not implement `iTest::foo`.

With full names, your declarations are as follows:

```
class iTest
{
public:
    enum eLevel
    {
        Info,
    };
    virtual void foo( iTest::eLevel l ) = 0;
};

class cTest : public iTest
{
public:
    enum eLevel
    {
        Info,
    };
    virtual void foo( cTest::eLevel l )
    {
    }
};
```

As one can see, `foo(iTest::eLevel)` is not the same as `foo(cTest::eLevel)`, thus `cTest` is still an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

You can either remove `cTest::eLevel` completely, or declare `cTest::foo` as

```
class cTest : public iTest
{
public:
    enum eLevel
    {
        Info,
    };
    virtual void foo( iTest::eLevel l )
    {
    }
};
```